# Jquery autocomplete, Cookies, Session ID Reset on form post only in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, autocomplete

Ok my problem is rather difficult to explain but here it goes.

I have a form with input fields and one of them is an (jQuery) autocomplete field.
This form is shown in the backend of my website, secured with a login combined with a sessionID.

**The problem:**
 - When I post the form without touching the autocomplete field, no problem there
 - When I touch the autocomplete field (even without typing anything), the sessionID is changed when I post the form. So I'm logged out.
 - No iframes used
 - Problem **only** when using IE6+ (all versions), works perfect in chrome, safari and firefox!

Comment: IE6? Really? Maybe refer the user to a modern browser? ;-) But seriously, what have you tried so far? Show us some code

Comment: Ok, I discovered that after logging out there is a second sessionID added when using IE.

Comment: @pc-shooter - I use IE11, but tested it in different versions of IE ;-).

Comment: Ok the solution in php: 

session.cookie_domain('.mydomain.com');

Comment: Put that as a nice formatted answer. Yes, your allowed, even encouraged to do so!